# GDAL writing data problem

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I have tried below code in python using the Spyder IDE to write data using GDAL but all I get is .tiff file named BnDSM with 0 bytes but when I restart my python kernel data appears.

```
driver = dsm.GetDriver()
outDataset = driver.Create("E:/PracticeData/BnDSM.tif", cols1,rows1, 1)
outBand = outDataset.GetRasterBand(1)
geoTransform = dsm.GetGeoTransform()
outDataset.SetGeoTransform(geoTransform )
outBand.WriteArray(BnDSM,0,0)
OutDataset=None
outBand =None
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GDAL doesn't actually write the data to disk until the dataset is dereferenced. This is a well known "[gotcha](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#Savingandclosingdatasetsdatasources)".

Your code doesn't dereference the dataset (by deleting the variable or setting it to None) because you have a typo, i.e `OutDataset = None` instead of `outDataset = None`. Note the difference in case and Python is case-sensitive.

Normally this wouldn't matter as the variable would get dereferenced and the data written to disk when the script finishes. However, when running in an IDE like Spyder  which holds the final state of the script open to aid debugging, the variable doesn't get dereferenced and the data is not written to disk until you restart your kernel. Not all IDEs do this, I know PyScripter does as well.

Also note that you should dereference the outBand variable *before* the outDataset variable to avoid the possibility of [crashing Python](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#Pythoncrashesifyouuseanobjectafterdeletinganobjectithasarelationshipwith).